# Is there a way to see Angular's webpack configuration?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-4

I'm experimenting with `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` but sometimes it's hard to know what needs to be changed, as I can't see the original Angular-created configuration.

I couldn't find a webpack configuration file (other than some test cases) in the `angular/angular or the angular/angular-cli` source so I'm guessing it's somehow generated on the fly based on `angular.json`.

Is there some way to print out / dump this full config? Even if it involves a temporary hack/workaround.

Versions in-use:

```
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^9.2.0",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.13",
"@angular/cli": "^9.1.13"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: as discussed in the comments, the current webpack config can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/webpack/configs)

---

Up to the version 1.7 of the CLI you could use `ng eject` (see [this](https://myview.rahulnivi.net/webpack-configuration-angular-cli/) for example, if you want to try it in an older project), but this has been disabled now AFAIK.

I have no experience myself with custom webpack configs, but you might want to have a look at 'ng eject alternatives', like [this one](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/customizing-angular-cli-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-v2-c655768b48cc) for example. Or perhaps you can find information on [this CLI-issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10618)

Comment: Sure, I'm using `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` already and it works pretty well, but I'd like to see what configuration angular is actually using. `custom-webpack` only lets you append new stuff to it.

Comment: Check out this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13737 . The link they provide ("The webpack config files can be found here") is not valid anymore, but maybe this one helps: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/webpack/configs ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/webpack/configs looks pretty good: It looks like webpack config, and it's in the master branch too so it must be up to date. Do you want to update the answer to point to this file and I'll accept it?